# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non existing account with Google+ Sign In

Tags: android, google-plus

Had a strange Exception reported from Google Play for an app with Google+ Sign In

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non existing account *******@gmail.com
```

Looking at the stack trace, I saw that it's being thrown in the following line of code

```
final String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context,
                            mPlusClient.getAccountName(),
                            scope);
```

The documentation for `GoogleAuthUtil` states that `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown only when the method call is made on the main thread, but I have wrapped the entire thing in an `AsyncTask`. Searching on Google doesn't throw up any results for this particular exception.. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to get a bearer token for an invalid account. Are you using the standard Google+ Sign-In button? And, if so, have you checked that the account you are logging in with has a valid Google+ account? It might have been suspended for a real-name violation.

Comment: We have the same code for Google+ sign in as given in the docs, but we use a custom styled button. And this happened to a user, not to an account we were trying to log in with.